# Copy the contents(including headers) of a ListView to a DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview, oledb

I have a `ListView` that has values from a `database`. I used two `MS Access OLEDB Statements` to produce the data I have. So I used two `While Loops`. The second `OLEDB Statement` is with reference to the first. How do I insert all the contents of my `ListView` to a `DataGridView`?

Here is my code for the two `While loops` that is used to call out the `OLEDB Statements`:

```
        Dim connectionstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\STSlog.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
        Dim command, command2, command3 As New OleDbCommand
        Dim commstring, commstring2, commstring3 As String
        Dim searchstring As String

        commstring = "SELECT DISTINCT empname FROM data WHERE ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' ORDER BY empname ASC"
        command = New OleDbCommand(commstring, conn)

        commstring3 = "SELECT SUM([Regular]) AS sRegular, SUM(OT) AS sOT FROM data WHERE ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' "
        command3 = New OleDbCommand(commstring3, conn)

        MainLView.Clear()
        MainLView.GridLines = True
        MainLView.FullRowSelect = True
        MainLView.View = View.Details
        MainLView.MultiSelect = True
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Employee Name", 290)
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Total Regular", 200)
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Total Overtime", 200)
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Total Hours", 200)

        conn.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim RegSum, OTSum, Total As Decimal

        While reader.Read

            searchstring = reader("empname")

            commstring2 = "SELECT SUM([Regular]) AS sReg, SUM(OT) AS sOT FROM data WHERE empname = '" & searchstring & "' AND ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' "
            command2 = New OleDbCommand(commstring2, conn)

            Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = command2.ExecuteReader()

            While reader2.Read

                RegSum = (reader2("sReg"))
                OTSum = (reader2("sOT"))
                Total = Format((RegSum + OTSum), "0.0")

                With MainLView.Items.Add(reader("empname"))
                    .subitems.add(reader2("sReg"))
                    .subitems.add(reader2("sOT"))
                    .subitems.add(Total)

                End With

            End While

        End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added columns first to my `DataGridView` then inserted the data from the database using `DataGridView Rows`.

```
         Dim connectionstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\STSlog.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
        Dim command, command2, command3 As New OleDbCommand
        Dim commstring, commstring2, commstring3 As String
        Dim searchstring As String

        commstring = "SELECT DISTINCT empname FROM data WHERE ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' ORDER BY empname ASC"
        command = New OleDbCommand(commstring, conn)

        commstring3 = "SELECT SUM([Regular]) AS sRegular, SUM(OT) AS sOT FROM data WHERE ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' "
        command3 = New OleDbCommand(commstring3, conn)

        MainLView.Clear()
        MainLView.GridLines = True
        MainLView.FullRowSelect = True
        MainLView.View = View.Details
        MainLView.MultiSelect = True
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Employee Name", 290)
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Total Regular", 200)
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Total Overtime", 200)
        MainLView.Columns.Add("Total Hours", 200)

        Dim col1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Dim col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Dim col3 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Dim col4 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        col1.HeaderText = "Employee Name"
        col2.HeaderText = "Total Regular"
        col3.HeaderText = "Total Overtime"
        col4.HeaderText = "Total Hours"
        ReportDGV.Columns.Add(col1)
        ReportDGV.Columns.Add(col2)
        ReportDGV.Columns.Add(col3)
        ReportDGV.Columns.Add(col4)

        conn.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim RegSum, OTSum, Total As Decimal

        While reader.Read

            searchstring = reader("empname")

            commstring2 = "SELECT SUM([Regular]) AS sReg, SUM(OT) AS sOT FROM data WHERE empname = '" & searchstring & "' AND ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' "
            command2 = New OleDbCommand(commstring2, conn)

            Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = command2.ExecuteReader()

            While reader2.Read

                RegSum = (reader2("sReg"))
                OTSum = (reader2("sOT"))
                Total = Format((RegSum + OTSum), "0.0")

                With MainLView.Items.Add(reader("empname"))
                    .subitems.add(reader2("sReg"))
                    .subitems.add(reader2("sOT"))
                    .subitems.add(Total)

                    Dim row As String() = New String() {reader("empname"), reader2("sReg"), reader2("sOT"), Total}
                    ReportDGV.Rows.Add(row)

                End With

            End While

        End While
```